# AllRowsReader class with token range

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, astyanax

This is an example of using **AllRowsReader** class from **Astyanax** recipes:

```
reader = new AllRowsReader.Builder<>(keyspace, columnFamily)
        .withPageSize(1000)
        .withConcurrencyLevel(10)
        .withPartitioner(null)
        .withConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.CL_ONE)
        .withIncludeEmptyRows(false)
        .withTokenRange(startToken, endToken)
        .forEachRow(new Function<Row<String, String>, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(@Nullable Row<String, String> row) {
                startToken = keyspace.getPartitioner().getTokenForKey(row.getRawKey());

                // some other statements

                return true;
            }
        })
        .build();

reader.call();
```

where

```
startToken = keyspace.getPartitioner().getMinToken();
lastToken = keyspace.getPartitioner().getMaxToken();
```

If to run **AllRowsReader** without "*withTokenRange(startToken, endToken)*" then all works fine. But with "*withTokenRange(startToken, endToken)*" not all rows are fetched during column family reading.

**AllRowsReader's** source has this code:

```
if (this.concurrencyLevel != null || startToken != null|| endToken != null) {
    List<TokenRange> tokens = partitioner.splitTokenRange(
            startToken == null ? partitioner.getMinToken() : startToken, 
            endToken == null   ? partitioner.getMinToken() : endToken, 
            this.concurrencyLevel == null ? 1 : this.concurrencyLevel);

            for (TokenRange range : tokens) {
                subtasks.add(makeTokenRangeTask(range.getStartToken(), range.getEndToken()));
            }
}
```

Later *partitioner.getMinToken()* reverts to *maxToken*. So I don't understand what is the difference from my approach? Why **AllRowsReader** with *minToken/maxToken* works differnt from **AllRowsReader** without them?

If operation is teminated, I execute it again with the last *startToken* (so it must be a shift). But in this case I see some rows were fetched before. And this is confusing me too...

P.S. **Astyanax** automatically determines **Murmur3Partitioner**.

Thanks for any help.

Links:
[AllRowsReader source](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/blob/master/astyanax-recipes/src/main/java/com/netflix/astyanax/recipes/reader/AllRowsReader.java),
[Murmur3Partitioner source](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/blob/master/astyanax-cassandra/src/main/java/com/netflix/astyanax/partitioner/Murmur3Partitioner.java)

Answer (score 0):

Dmitry,
Treat the token range as a ring,as the circle completes start will be equal to end.Thats why in astyanax code there are setting the same token as min and max.

```
startToken == null ? partitioner.getMinToken() : startToken, 
            endToken == null   ? partitioner.getMinToken() : endToken
```

I hope this clarifies your answer.Let me know if you have doubts

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can't check it. We stopped using Cassandra and moved to Aerospike.